# Solution for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\kappa\text{e}^{\left(b-c\right)t}\right)^{-\frac{b}{b-c}}e^{-at}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\kappa\text{e}^{\left(b-c\right)t}\right)^{-\frac{b}{b-c}}e^{-at}dt
\end{equation}

Intuitively, I have started to try hypergeometric function but could not go further. I have tried on Mathematica and saw that there is a solution. However, I would like to understand how it can be solved analytically. I appreciate any solution or hints.

I am also interested in the indefinite form of the integral.

Comment: Suppose we have $\kappa > 0, a > 0, c > b > 0$. Then $t = -\ln(u)/(c - b)$ gives [Euler's integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Integral_formulas) of ${_2 F_1}$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks! I see the point!