# definite and indefinite integral with hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

I am trying to find the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\kappa\text{e}^{\left(b-c\right)t}\right)^{-\frac{b}{b-c}}e^{-at}dt
\end{equation}

I would like to know whether it is correct to start integrating the following term without integral bounds.

$$\int\left(1+\kappa\text{e}^{\left(b-c\right)t}\right)^{-\frac{b}{b-c}}e^{-at}dt$$

For ths last equation, I find that the solution is

$$-\frac{e^{-\rho t}{_{2}F_{1}}\left[\frac{b}{b-c},-\frac{\rho}{b-c},-\frac{c-b+\rho}{b-c},e^{\left(b-c\right)t}\kappa\right]}{\rho}$$

After finding this solution is it correct to put

$$\left[-\frac{e^{-\rho t}{_{2}F_{1}}\left[\frac{b}{b-c},-\frac{\rho}{b-c},-\frac{c-b+\rho}{b-c},e^{\left(b-c\right)t}\kappa\right]}{\rho}\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}=\frac{{_{2}F_{1}}\left[\frac{b}{b-c},-\frac{\rho}{b-c},-\frac{c-b+\rho}{b-c},\kappa\right]}{\rho}$$

All parameters $\rho$, $\kappa$, $a$, $b$, $c$ are constant and positive terms.

If not, how should I proceed?

Comment: What is $\rho$?  What are your assumptions on the parameters $a,b,c,\kappa$?

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I edited the question.

Comment: You [lost a minus sign](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3734163) in the argument of ${_2 F_1}$. This is not the most convenient form for an antiderivative if $c < b$ because $1 - a/(b - c)$ can become a nonpositive integer.